# Swift compiler crashes on switch statement, need workaround

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I've got code that basically looks like this, although I'm not sure that this distilled version exactly reproduces the compiler crash:

```
enum Response<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(String)
}

struct ResponseData {
    let someData = "some data"
}

func evaluate() {
    let response = Response.Success(ResponseData())

    switch response {
    case let .Success(data):
        println("Got response with \(data)")
    case let .Failure(reason):
        println("Got failure: \(reason)")
    default: ()
    }
}
```

The Xcode editor doesn't detect any problems, but when I build, the compiler crashes with this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

When I comment out the .Success case, I can build just fine. I'm guessing the Swift compiler doesn't like generics as associated values with the enum. However, that pattern is extremely useful for me, and it makes the code much more readable. Any idea how I can work around this? As far as I can tell, there's no way to access associated values except with a switch statement.

I should also mention that I have found [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088790/swift-switch-case-compiler-error), but have not managed to make much use of the solutions presented.

**Edit** Actually the following already throws a seg-fault:

```
enum Response<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(String)
}

struct ResponseData {
    let someData = "some data"
}

func evaluate() {
    let response = Response.Success(ResponseData())
}
```

> unimplemented IR generation feature non-fixed multi-payload enum layout
>   enum Response {

Comment: According the other question you referenced, it seems to be a compiler error, so try using an `if let` statement instead of the switch.

Comment: What is the syntax for that? Note that I need to access the associated value of .Success. "if let response == .Success(data) { ... }" and "if response == .Success(let data) { ... }" give me errors.

Comment: I experience a segfault 11 with XC 6.1.3

Comment: See this one: http://owensd.io/2014/08/06/fixed-enum-layout.html which links to a gist of one of the SO "gods"

Comment: Check out Rob Rix's Result library. He's worked out all the gotchas for building a type like your Response type.https://github.com/antitypical/Result

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have it working now - see the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to the solution really goes to everyone who commented above.

The problem seems to be that the Swift compiler wants to know exactly how large the enum is in memory. Generics make that impossible, thus the compiler does not behave correctly.

The solution I went with was taken from Rob Rix's library, which is to box the generic in another type. Note that it must be a class, since a reference has a known size but a struct with the generic does not.

The @autoclosure solution seemed interesting also, but it does not work with the latest version of Xcode. This was by design; as I understand, the developers don't want closures to run each time the enum is evaluated.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: In case you're still monitoring this thread, did you manage to find any documentation on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use only objects that inherit from NSObject

Like this

```
enum Result<T: NSObject>: Printable {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(NSError)

    var description: String {
        switch self{
        case .Success(let obj):
            return obj.description
        case .Error(let error):
            return error.description
    }
}
```

And then

```
let r = Result.Success("Xcode")

r.description
```

UPD:
You can do something like this

```
@objc
protocol ResultObjectProtocol {
    var description: String { get }
}

extension NSDictionary: ResultObjectProtocol {}

enum Result<T: ResultObjectProtocol>: Printable {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(NSError)

    var description: String {
        switch self{
        case .Success(let obj):
            return obj.description
        case .Failure(let error):
            return error.description
        }
    }
}

let r = Result.Success(["d" : 132]).description
```

Note: `var description` - only for example

Upd. (Swift 4)
You are free to use generic type in enum:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error(Error)
}
```